# Divide S3 prefix to list of object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Example, I have a path(prefix) like this:  `A/B/C/`

I want to get bellow list：

```
[{name:"A",path:"A/"},
 {name:"B",path:"A/B/",
 {name:"C",path:"A/B/C/"
]
```

I can split the path to a array, then loop the array to build the new list of object.
But in my mind, I just know there should be a simple and smarter way to achieve this by using reducer, but just stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that you could use a reducer. Something like this:

```js
const str = "A/B/C/"

const arr = str.split("/").filter(Boolean).reduce((acc, name) => {
  const path = [...acc.map(o => o.name), name].join("/") + "/"
  return [...acc, { name, path }]
}, [])

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Good catch on the empty string at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with map, but maybe not as cleanly as you were anticipating:

```js
const result = 'A/B/C'
  .split('/')
  .filter(x => x)
  .map((name, i, arr) => {
    const prev = arr[i - 1];
    return prev
      ? { name, path: `${prev.name}${name}/` }
      : { name, path: `${name}/` };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

My odd solution, but I think sdgluck's is the cleanest answer.

```
arr = "A/B/C/"
    .split("/")
    .filter(e => e)
    .map((e, i, a) => {
        a2 = a.filter((el, ix) => {
            if (ix <= i) return el;
        });

        return  {[e] : a2.join("/")};
    });
```